# SQL Server - Group by few columns and put in one row in appropriate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do the task but not quite imagine how to implement.
i have the table in the SQL Server database with following columns:

```
ID     Start    End      Time       Ostart    OEnd  
1       111     222   01-01-2013     111      555  
1       222     333   02-01-2013     111      555  
1       333     444   03-01-2013     111      555
1       444     555   04-01-2013     111      555
1       444     555   01-01-2013     444      666  
1       555     666   02-01-2013     444      666
```

I want to take an intermediate points from Start to End until End doesn't equal OEnd and put in one row. For this example the result table should be with 2 rows : for 111 - 555 Ostart-OEnd with intermediate points 222-333-444 and 444-666 Ostart-Oend with intermidiate point 555. The max count of intermediate points are 5. So the result table would like this :

```
 ID     OStart   OEnd     Time      Point1     Time1      Point2    Time2      Point3   Point4   Point5  
 1       111     555   01-01-2013     222    02-01-2013    333    03-01-2013    444      
 1       444     666   01-01-2013     555    02-01-2013
```

How can i get such result table?

Comment: Rereading this, why is it in the MySQL category?  Is it supposed to be MS SQL Server?

Comment: Shouldn't assume it's mis-tagged without clarification from OP, imo.

Comment: In the description, he says SQL Server, and the naming convention for columns looks like SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result into multiple columns from your multiple row values. If you apply the `row_number()` windowing function then you can get the point values 1-5:

```
select id, ostart, oend, Point1, Point2, Point3, Point4, Point5
from
(
  select id, [end], ostart, oend,
    'Point'
      +cast(row_number() over(partition by id, ostart 
                              order by start) as varchar(10)) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max([end])
  for seq in (Point1, Point2, Point3, Point4, Point5)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/943f0/5).

If you want to PIVOT on two columns, then you will need to unpivot and then pivot the data:

```
select id, ostart, oend, 
  Point1, Time1, Point2, Time2, 
  Point3, Time3, Point4, Time4, Point5, Time5
from
(
  select id, ostart, oend, col+cast(seq as varchar(10)) col,
    value
  from
  (
    select id, [end], time, ostart, oend,
      cast(row_number() over(partition by id, ostart 
                                order by start) as varchar(10)) seq
    from yourtable
  ) src
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Time', convert(varchar(10), time, 120) union all
    select 'Point', cast([end] as varchar(10))
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (Point1, Time1, Point2, Time2, 
              Point3, Time3, Point4, Time4, Point5, Time5)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/943f0/16)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what i need. Could you tell me how to skip the last point? Because now it put the OEnd value there. I need just intermediate points.

Comment: after `from yourtable` add `WHERE [end] <> oend`

Comment: Thanks.One more question. How can I pivot on multiple columns? For example add TIME column also.

Comment: @Alexander You would have to implement both unpivot and pivot to get the result.

Comment: Could you please help me with this? I'm not familiar with pivot / unpivot

Comment: @Alexander You will have to provide more details in your original post if you want to pivot by two columns.

Comment: I've edited the post. See the new design of the result table I need to get.